# Height 100% in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am working on a directory and want the Google Map to be responsive so I have to define the height to 100% in JS. The following is the code I have used:

```
var mapdiv = document.getElementById("company_map"); 
mapdiv.style.width = '1000px'; 
mapdiv.style.height= '205px';

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapdiv, myOptions);
```

So I need to change mapdiv.style.height='205px'; to mapdiv.style.height='100%'; but % is not working.

Comment: Do any other elements exhibit the same behavior with height:100%, or just Google Maps

Comment: 100% of what exactly, the parent element, the window or something else entirely ?

Comment: just the map as there is overlay shadow. which is working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the parents height and set it in pixels instead, as 100% means the full height of the parent element

```
var mapdiv = document.getElementById("company_map"),
    parent = mapdiv.parentNode;

mapdiv.style.width  = '1000px';
mapdiv.style.height = parent.clientHeight + 'px';

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var map = new google.maps.Map(mapdiv, myOptions);
```

Comment: This is not the same as `height: 100%`, because if the window (or the parent element) is resized, this child will not be resized as well.

Comment: this is working but i am not able to set the height of parent to 100%

Answer (score 0):

[works for me...](http://jsfiddle.net/Uk8cE/)

css:

```
body, html{
  height: 100%;
}

div{
  background-color: red;
}
```

js:

```
var div = document.getElementById('company_map');
div.style.width = '200px';
div.style.height = '200px';

div.onclick = function(){
    div.style.height = '100%';
};
```

Make sure you set a height on the parent element, otherwise 100% has no meaning...